# Heroku app shows error - relation does not exist

Tags: spring, heroku

I am deploying my first app on Heroku and I get this error below. When I run it on localhost everything is fine. First time it happened I deleted the app and created it again but I still can't access /history. I don't know where to look for the error. The rest of the app is working normally.

The error from Heroku logs:

```
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354036+00:00 app[web.1]:     select
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354037+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.id as id1_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354038+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.booking_time as booking_2_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354038+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.cancelled_on as cancelle3_1_,

2022-05-07T17:02:52.354038+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.check_in as check_in4_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354039+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.check_out as check_ou5_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354039+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.comments as comments6_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354040+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.email as email7_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354040+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.first_name as first_na8_1_,

2022-05-07T17:02:52.354040+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.guest_id as guest_i20_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354041+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.is_cancelled as is_cance9_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354041+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.is_completed as is_comp10_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354042+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.last_name as last_na11_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354042+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.lat as lat12_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354042+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.lng as lng13_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354042+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.payment_id as payment21_1_,

2022-05-07T17:02:52.354043+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.pet_kilograms as pet_kil14_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354043+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.pet_name as pet_nam15_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354043+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.phone_number as phone_n16_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354044+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.property_id as propert22_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354044+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.total_nights as total_n17_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354044+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.total_price as total_p18_1_,
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354045+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.updated as updated19_1_ 
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354045+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354045+00:00 app[web.1]:         booking_history bookinghis0_ 
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354045+00:00 app[web.1]:     where
2022-05-07T17:02:52.354046+00:00 app[web.1]:         bookinghis0_.guest_id=?

2022-05-07T17:02:52.356294+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-07 17:02:52.356 TRACE 4 --- [nio-

6847-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.360850+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-07 17:02:52.360  WARN 4 --- [nio-6847-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2022-05-07T17:02:52.360887+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-07 17:02:52.360 ERROR 4 --- [nio-6847-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "booking_history" does not exist

2022-05-07T17:02:52.360888+00:00 app[web.1]:   Position: 874
2022-05-07T17:02:52.361573+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-07 17:02:52.361 DEBUG 4 --- [nio-6847-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

2022-05-07T17:02:52.363391+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-07 17:02:52.363 ERROR 4 --- [nio-6847-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363392+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363393+00:00 app[web.1]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "booking_history" does not exist

2022-05-07T17:02:52.363394+00:00 app[web.1]:   Position: 874
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363394+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2674) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363395+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2364) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363395+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363396+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:484) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]

2022-05-07T17:02:52.363396+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:404) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363396+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:162) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363397+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363397+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363398+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-05-07T17:02:52.363398+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
```

Controller:

> 

```
@GetMapping("/history")
public String showAllHistory(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser user, Model model) {
    List<TitleBookingServiceModel> serviceModels = this.bookingHistoryService.findAllBookingsByUserId(user.getUserId());

    List<TitleBookingViewModel> viewModels = serviceModels
            .stream()
            .map(s -> this.mapper.map(s, TitleBookingViewModel.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (viewModels.isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("noContent", new Message("There are no bookings at the moment!"));
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("viewModels", viewModels);
    }
    return "history";
}
```

Repository:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT b FROM BookingHistoryEntity as b WHERE b.guest.id = :userId")
List<BookingHistoryEntity> findAllByGuestId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

Comment: Have you run your migrations on Heroku?

Comment: the steps that I have followed are more or less like the ones described here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku. I am not sure how and when should I run these migrations? Isn't what I have done enough?

Comment: Do you see where that article links to [this page about running migrations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-database-migrations-for-java-apps)? Whether you follow that guide or do something else, _somehow_ your database needs to have tables etc. created.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I have added the `DATABASE_URL` config var in my heroku app and still I was getting the same exception (In local everything worked just fine).

Then I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41020436) that heroku creates 3 additional environment variables at runtime:

```
JDBC_DATABASE_URL
JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME
JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD
```

Then I added those 3 config vars in my app, and the app automatically restated. Then I hit my endpoint and the exception was gone!

Additionally, you might have to add `currentSchema=<schema name>` at the end of your `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` and `DATABASE_URL` strings, so that your spring boot application points to your `<schema name>` and not `public` schema.

Ex: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo?sslmode=require&currentSchema=student`

Hope this helps.
Cheers!